# Can jqGrid summer footer sum strings and numbers?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have here included the screenshot of table.

[image]

Comment: Post your jqgrid code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem as this screenshot(http://s11.postimg.org/61za32rgz/Client_Sales.jpg) shows I added another column just to add it, I needed to make (Dummy Year-To-Date) integer, so I could sum them up all.

Lastly, I need to set hidden:true so that would hide the (Dummy column).

Thanks. : )

Answer (score 0):

No, javacript needs it to be a number to add.

To convert your `Year-to-Date` column from String to Integer, add the `formatter` attribute to your jqGrid function

```
formatter: function (cellValue, options, rawData, action) {
        return parseInt(rawData[2]);  //Assuming your Year-to-Date is the third column in your JSON object.
}
```

Comment: Hi @Saravanan ,
Thank you for your time answering the question,
It didn't work for me.